# Можно ли так сказать?

Tags: общие-вопросы

В турпоходе нет скуки и **постоянности места пребывания.**

Comment: @Ивона, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее было бы сказать "нет постоянства мест", а не мест**а**, ибо фраза - "постоянство места", указывает на то, что само место подвержено изменению, а здесь, как я понимаю, происходит именно **смена мест**. Слово же постоянность, действительно,более применимо ко времени,  к событиям, нежели к предметам.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, что именно вас тут смущает.
Некоторая несерьезность, ироничность имеет место.
Ну так это явно не деловой стиль.
А для рекламы или свободной беседы - вполне.

А контекст не укажете?
Где эта фраза будет, в каком тексте, на каком заборе?

Answer (score 0):

В этой фразе нет ошибок, но стилистически её можно улучшить, особенно, если она предназначена для какой-то презентации.

1. Я бы повторил "нет" перед "постоянностью места", поскольку "скука" и "место пребывания" - понятия из двух разных миров (мира идей и мира вещей) - ведь здесь это не гротескный приём ("нет совести и стекла" - из недавней телерекламы). Места меняются, причём ни в одном месте не скучно - видимо, таков желаемый смысл.
2. Постоянность и постоянство - очень близкие синонимы, но они в разной степени подходят к разным случаям употребления. По моим ощущениям, "постоянность" лучше связывается с "пребыванием" в каком-либо месте (с длительным во времени действием нахождения), а "постоянство" - с постоянным "местом" (одним и тем же местом - каждый раз выбираемым). Поэтому в зависимости от требуемого акцента ("места меняются" или "надолго нигде не задержимся") стилистически я предпочёл бы такие обороты (первый лучше воспринимается):

В турпоходе нет скуки и нет постоянства места пребывания.

В турпоходе нет скуки и нет постоянности пребывания в одном месте.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь лишняя буква - ”И”. Идёт перечисление. Турпоход - это уже определенное лишение себя неких удобств и благ цивилизации. Но как и у всего, у благ есть и отрицательная сторона. Скука - одно из них. Спутником скуки является: сытость, тепло и крыша над головой. Без этого теплокровное существо погибает. Постоянное место - отвечает всем этим условиям. Само слово "турпоход" самодостаточно. Всё остальное - контекст.

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Даже красиво получается.

Comment: Хотелось бы видеть более подробный и аргументированный ответ.